# How can I make my laptop go to sleep 5 minutes *after* closing the lid?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

Windows 7 can turn go to sleep when I close my lid, or after a period of inactivity. Fine.

I don't want it to go to sleep immediately after closing the lid; I want it to wait 5 minutes and *then* go to sleep.

Can this be done?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355606/detect-laptop-lid-closure-and-opening was about the needed API for creating such program. Still trying to decipher what it means. I suppose I can make a tiny C# apps to deal with it

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @soandos I close up my laptop around 5pm all the time, only to have the phone ring as I'm still packing it up with some final thing someone wants to check.

Answer (score 3):

This capability isn't built into windows 7, and I'm not aware of software that will do this (thought that certainly doesn't mean no such software exists). If you have any programming ability (and your profile indicates you're no slouch here), this stackoverflow question will get you started building your own:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355606/detect-laptop-lid-closure-and-opening

In a nutshell: set the default action in Windows 7 to not do anything, but have your program running as a service and handle the `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message. When you spot one with the right data, set a timer for 5 minutes and put the machine to sleep when it goes off.  Different data on that message or messages that indicate user activity (like WM_MOUSEMOVE or WM_KEYDOWN) might cancel the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing (Windows 8.1 now). Lenovo used to have a utility in its power management program that did this, but it's no longer there (mostly as Windows machines start back up a lot faster than they used to).

I'm currently thinking there might be a way to create a scheduled task which is triggered by an event, which then starts a timer, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The following AutoHotkey code will put the machine to sleep if the lid stays closed for 1 minute.  You must configure Windows power settings to do nothing when the lid is closed. The code will detect the lid closed, set a time for 60 seconds, and, if the lid is not reopened, it will suspend the computer.

I largely used code provided by "Linear Spoon" in the [AutoHotkey forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=23654). My contribution is a few lines near the bottom.

```
#Persistent
MINUTES := 1
MinuteCount := 0

start_Lidwatcher()

/*
 By Linear Spoon
   7/28/2013
 This script should work for Vista+

 Details:
 Use Start_LidWatcher to begin monitoring the lid state.
 r := Start_LidWatcher()

 When the state changes, the function "LidStateChange" will be called.
 LidStateChange should have the following format:
 LidStateChange(newstate)
 {
   ...
 }

 newstate will be one of two values:
 "opened" = The lid was opened
 "closed" = The lid was closed

 Note: It's possible that this function will be immediately called after 
       using Start_LidWatcher with the lid's current state (usually open).

 When the application no longer needs to monitor the lid state,
 call Stop_LidWatcher with the return value from Start_LidWatcher.
 Pass it the return value from Start_LidWatcher.
 Stop_LidWatcher(r)

*/

Start_LidWatcher()
{
  
  VarSetCapacity(guid, 16)
  ;GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE
  Numput(0xBA3E0F4D, guid, 0, "uint"), Numput(0x4094B817, guid, 4, "uint")
  Numput(0x63D5D1A2, guid, 8, "uint"), Numput(0xF3A0E679, guid, 12, "uint")

  r := DllCall("RegisterPowerSettingNotification", "ptr", A_ScriptHwnd, "ptr", &guid, "uint", 0)
  if (!r || ErrorLevel)
  {
    ;MSDN says check GetLastError if the return value was NULL.
    Msgbox % "RegisterPowerSettingNotification failed with error: " (ErrorLevel ? ErrorLevel : A_LastError)
    return 0
  }
  OnMessage(0x218, "WM_POWERBROADCAST")
  return r
}

Stop_LidWatcher(r)
{
  DllCall("UnregisterPowerSettingNotification", "ptr", r)
  OnMessage(0x218, "")
}

WM_POWERBROADCAST(wparam, lparam)
{
  static fx := "LidStateChange"
  if (wparam = 0x8013)
  {
    ;data = 0 = closed
    ;data = 1 = opened
    if isFunc(fx)    
      %fx%(Numget(lparam+20, 0, "uchar") ? "opened" : "closed")
  }
  return 1
}

/*
 * The following code added by Kevin Kleinfelter. Copyright is in the public domain.
 */
LidStateChange(newstate)
{
    Global MINUTES
    Global MinuteCount
    ;msgbox, ding %newstate%
    if (newstate = "opened") {
        SetTimer, TickTock, off
    }
    if (newstate = "closed") {
        MinuteCount := MINUTES
        setTimer, TickTock, 60000
    }
}

return
TickTock:
MinuteCount := MinuteCount - 1
if (MinuteCount <= 0) {
DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 1, "int", 0)
}
return
```