# How can I configure Windows 10 to shutdown AFTER a certain amount of time AFTER I close the lid?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, shutdown

I want to make it so after I close the lid:

1. First, the system goes to sleep
2. After 10 minutes, the system shuts down

Is this possible?

I saw this question, but it is for Windows 7 and I am asking for Windows 10: [How can I make my laptop go to sleep 5 minutes *after* closing the lid?](https://superuser.com/questions/320295/how-can-i-make-my-laptop-go-to-sleep-5-minutes-after-closing-the-lid).

Comment: The sequence of events you want can't be done. OS version doesn't matter.

Comment: Just shut down when the lid closes.  There is no value in suspending first before shutting down. Otherwise, as noted, what you want cannot be done.

Comment: Perhaps setting the lid-close action to Hibernate will be enough? ([link](https://pureinfotech.com/change-close-lid-action-windows-11/))

Comment: @John There is value. If I close the lid and then open it within 5 minutes, I want it to get out of sleep quickly.

Comment: @harrymc I am doing hybernate now but I want something faster.

Comment: @ChanganAuto if you reply with that as an answer I can accept it.